# Retrieving word from pandas column that matches words in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with text. This text can contain the name of countries. I want to have a list of all countries mentioned in a column in the same row as the text. I already have a series with the countries I want to extract.

```
    SomeText                          | ... | .... | CountryInText
    Something Canada                  |     |      |   
    RUSSIAAreACountry                 |     |      |   
    Mexicoand Brazil is South of USA




    SomeText                          | ... | .... | CountryInText
    Something Canada                  |     |      |  Canada 
    RUSSIAAreACountry                 |     |      |  Russia
    Mexicoand Brazil is South of USA  |     |      |  Mexico, Brazil, USA
```

I've tried with

```
pd.Series(df['SomeText'].str.findall(f"({'|'.join(countryname['CommonName'])})"))
```

However, this gives me a list of object that I can't match back to the original dataframe. The countryname['CommonName'] is a series of country names.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522281/how-to-loop-through-pandas-df-column-finding-if-string-contains-any-string-from/59522472?noredirect=1#comment107292510_59522472) what you're looking for?

Comment: Why would you use `findall`? What happens if you have two country names in `SomeText`?

Comment: It looks like what you actually want may be different from how you phrased it. Based on your example, it appears that what you want is the rightmost column of a particular row to consist of all countries that appear in the leftmost column of that row. Is that correct?

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes that is correct, sorry - I am updating the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An solution (with a small testing example) using `re` package (for more flexibility):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"SomeText": ["Something Canada", "RUSSIAAreACountry"]})
countryname = pd.Series({"CommonName": ["Canada", "Russia"]})
df["CountryInText"] = df["SomeText"].str.title().map(lambda x: 
                                         re.findall('|'.join(countryname['CommonName']), x, re.I))
```

**UPDATE (based on Erfan's feedback in the comment):**

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"SomeText": ["Something Canada", "RUSSIAAreACountry"]})
countryname = pd.Series({"CommonName": ["Canada", "Russia"]})
df["CountryInText"] = df["SomeText"].str.title().str.findall('|'.join(countryname['CommonName']), re.I)
```

**UPDATE 2 (based on the useful additional test cases posted by OP)**:

The approaches above would return Usa instead of USA. The one below takes care of that:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"SomeText": ["Something Canada",
                                "RUSSIAAreACountry", 
                                "Mexicoand Brazil is South of USA"]})
countryname = pd.Series({"CommonName": ["Canada", "Russia", "Mexico", "Brazil", "USA"]})
df["CountryInText"] = df["SomeText"].map(lambda x: [c for c in countryname['CommonName'] 
                                                    if c.lower() in x.lower()])
```

Comment: Better use a native pandas method: `Series.str.findall`

Comment: Yes besides that, but it was general comment, it does not make sense to use `re.findall` when we have a native pandas method @QuangHoang

Comment: Why the `.title()` and `.lower()` ?

Comment: @AMC the `title()` was for returning a country name with only the initials as capital letters (e.g. the OP example RUSSIA -> Russia). But that approach was not addressing properly the scenario added later (USA -> USA).
The last approach takes care of that test case too and it uses `lower()` to make the match case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

A bit too late and a dupe but I wrote the code, so I may as well:)

```
import pandas as pd
import re
countryname = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Name": ["Rep. of Congo", "Russia Long", "Canada Long"],
        "CommonName": ["Congo", "Russia", "Canada"]})
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "SomeText": ["Something Canada", "RUSSIAAreACountry", "Rep ofIreland", "Unrelated"],
        "CountryInText": ["","","",""]})
names = "|".join(list(countryname["CommonName"]))
```

Would give you:

countryname:

```
            Name CommonName
0  Rep. of Congo      Congo
1    Russia Long     Russia
2    Canada Long     Canada
```

df:

```
            SomeText CountryInText
0   Something Canada              
1  RUSSIAAreACountry              
2      Rep ofIreland              
3          Unrelated
```

names:

```
Congo|Russia|Canada
```

Then using findall and a simple function you can find all instances of strings in the common names and if anything is found pick the first one and make it a title case, or return an empty string if nothing is found. This approach ignores the All cap options and changes everything to Title Case. I also saw the rightmost name addition after I wrote the answer, so that is out as well.

```
# re.I is there to do case insensitive matching
df["CountryInText"] = df["SomeText"].str.findall(names, flags = re.I)
def cleanup(country_list):
    if len(country_list) > 0:
        return str(country_list[0])
    return ""
df["CountryInText"] = df["CountryInText"].apply(cleanup).apply(str.title)
```

Now df:

```
            SomeText CountryInText
0   Something Canada        Canada
1  RUSSIAAreACountry        Russia
2      Rep ofIreland              
3          Unrelated
```