# Search for string pattern in dataframe column, return each occurence and join to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm trying to do something similar to [How to loop through pandas df column, finding if string contains any string from a separate pandas df column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522281/how-to-loop-through-pandas-df-column-finding-if-string-contains-any-string-from), specifically the second problem

My initial dataframe `logs` contains the following:

```
ID DB  USER  MDX_TEXT
1  DB1  JOE  SELECT [ATTR1].[ATTR1].[THE_ATTR1] ON COLUMNS,[ATTR2].[ATTR2].[THE_ATTR2] ON ROWS FROM [THE_DB] WHERE [ATTR3].[ATTR3].[THE_ATTR3]
2  DB1  JAY  SELECT [ATTR1].[ATTR1].[THE_ATTR1] ON COLUMNS, [ATTR3].[ATTR3].[THE_ATTR3] ON ROWS FROM [THE_DB] WHERE [ATTR3].[ATTR3].[THE_ATTR3]
```

Using regex, I then extract the unique instances of `MDX_TEXT` per `ID`

```
# Step 1: Define a pattern to extract MDX regex pattern
import re
pattern = re.compile (r'(\[[\w ]+\]\.\[[\w ]+\](?:\.(?:Members|\[Q\d\]))?)')

# Step 2: Create a dataframe to store distinct list of MDX Query attributes, based on pattern
extrpat =  (
            logs['MDX_TEXT'].str.extractall(pattern)
                            .drop_duplicates()
                            .to_numpy()
           )
# Step 3: Create a dataframe to store distinct list of attributes used in a query
attr= pd.DataFrame(data=extrpat)
attr.rename({0: 'attrname'}, inplace=True, axis=1)

# Preview the first 5 lines of the attributes dataframe
attr.head()
```

Which results in:

```
attrname
[THE_ATTR1]
[THE_ATTR2]
[THE_ATTR3]
[THE_ATTR1]
[THE_ATTR3]
```

What I would like, is in addition to extracting the unique attributes in step 2, to also extract the `ID` and `USER`, like this:

```
ID  USER  attrname
1  JOE  [THE_ATTR1]
1  JOE  [THE_ATTR2]
1  JOE  [THE_ATTR3]
2  JAY  [THE_ATTR1]
2  JAY  [THE_ATTR3]
```

and then finally, join the `attr` and `logs` dataframes on the `ID`. The idea is to bring in a third dataframe `users`:

```
USER  LOC
JOE  NY
JIL  NJ
MAC  CA
```

...which I will join with the aforementioned on `USER` to end up with this:

```
ID  USER  LOC  attrname
1  JOE  NY  [THE_ATTR1]
1  JOE  NY  [THE_ATTR2]
1  JOE  NY  [THE_ATTR3]
2  JAY  NJ  [THE_ATTR1]
2  JAY  NJ  [THE_ATTR3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited).

The pattern piece is a good start, but then you have to merge / join it with the original dataframe:

```
df.index.name = "inx"
pattern = re.compile (r'(\[[\w ]+\]\.\[[\w ]+\])')

# extract the attributes. 
extracts = df.MDX_TEXT.str.extractall(pattern).rename(columns={0:"attrname"})

# join the result with the original dataframe. 
res = df.join(extracts).reset_index()[["ID", "USER", "attrname"]].drop_duplicates()

# take just the last part of each attribute name. 
res["attrname"] = res["attrname"].str.split(".", expand = True).iloc[:, -1]
```

The result is:

```
   ID USER attrname
0   1  JOE  [ATTR1]
1   1  JOE  [ATTR2]
2   1  JOE  [ATTR3]
3   2  JAY  [ATTR1]
4   2  JAY  [ATTR3]
```

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, but that's only one line in the attribute 'text'. I need to iterate over the whole dataframe, and I'm cautious of iterating over the dataframe.

Comment: Is the original data a dataframe with three columns? (I somehow missed that).